# Changing the appearance of a custom android checkbox without the image scaling?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a custom checkbox with these attributes:

```
android:id="@+id/map_toolbar_details"
android:layout_width="80px"
android:layout_height="106px"
android:scaleType="center"
macro:selectedResource="@drawable/map_toolbar_details_selected"
android:button="@drawable/map_toolbar_details"
```

When I load it up, the image gets stretched, even though it's set to scaleType center. If I set a background, I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_width="80px"
android:layout_height="106px"
change this part
make it whether exact size of the image or both 
wrap_content

### wrap_content

when you set another image background it will automatically adjust itself to that image size